# VBA Remove time from Date

Tags: vba

I'd like to remove the time from the date in cells (in the same column D) with a macro like this : 5/5/2006 12:00AM ==> 5/5/2006

The thing is the first cell to format is never the same. I've found a code on the net that might be good for me but don't work on my side:

```
Sub ConvertDates()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
For Each Rng In WorkRng
Rng.Value = VBA.Int(Rng.Value)
Next
WorkRng.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
End Sub
```

And why not simply format all the column without the hour? With a DateValue(.Value) function..

I'm a beginner in macros, sorry! Thanks for your precious help :)

Comment: what is it doing that is wrong?

Comment: I have a text box asking me the range (which is nice) but when I click 'ok', nothing happens after. Time is not removed

Comment: I t works for me, my guess is you have Date/times that are text that look like dates and not true dates.

Comment: Nop' I've checked, there are not in text format but in date..

Comment: The format of the cell will not change a text.  Try changing the format manually to `mm/dd/yyyy` and see if it changes, if it does not then it is text.  Or try `=istext(A1)`

Comment: Yes indeed, they seem to be in text (I didn't extract myself). I've tried to change from text to date with DATEVALUE or even just VALUE functions, but does'nt work neither. How can I change easily from text to dates? Thanks :)

Comment: That is a different question.  please remove this one as it is not the problem and ask a new question with examples of the data.  But before you do this is a common problem, search Google for an answer before asking.

Comment: Format only changes the display fo the data.  The fundamental nature of the data itself does not change.